# Can I change a FL_Window's caption other than in a constructor argument?

Tags: c++, fltk

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(int w, int h, const string& c)
: Fl_Window(w, h, c.c_str()) // Don't call constructor over here
{
    script.load_file(WIN_CONFIG_SCRIPT);

    int width = script.get_global_int("width");
    int height = script.get_global_int("height");

    const char* caption = script.get_global_string("caption").c_str();

    /** CALL CONSTRUCTOR NOW **/

    //NOTE: I don't know a way to change an FLTK Fl_Window's Caption after 
    //initialising it.

    Toolbar* toolbar = new Toolbar(0, 0, this->w(),30);
    toolbar->add_button("Hello");
    toolbar->add_button("World!");

    end();
}
```

How do I initialize the base class **inside** the constructor? Alternatively, how do I change an FLTK Fl_Window's caption **after** initialising it? Is there any *other* way out of this mess?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I initialize the base class inside the constructor?

You may not.

The base part of the instance must be initialised before the derived part of the instance or any of its members.

---

> How do I change an FLTK Fl_Window's caption after initialising it?

[The documentation](http://www.fltk.org/doc-1.1/Fl_Window.html) says you can call:

```
label("my caption")
```

What's wrong with that?

---

> Any other way out of this mess?

No.

---

Also, you should upgrade to FLTK 2.

Comment: (+1) Thanks. You've been helping me a lot these days, you've answered 3 or 4 of my other recent questions as well, so thanks again.

Comment: FLTK 2 is a dead branch unfortunately. Developers are focused on the FLTK 3 now. So I would suggest he either users FLTK 1.3 or FLTK 3. FLTK 2 is still (IMHO) way ahead of both, but gradually all good stuff in FLTK 2 will be ported to FLTK 3.

Comment: @Mr.Anubis: One is new. The other is not.